# fonts on pubspec.yaml, doesn't display my font correctly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

i recently change pubspec.yaml file but flutter can't display my font

```
  fonts:
    - family: Amatic
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/Amatic-Bold.ttf
       - asset: assets/fonts/Amatic-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Please provide your assets folder structure and pubspec file assets part as screenshots. It is hard to define what is wrong now without them

Answer (score 0):

`.yaml` files are case sensitive. So, you have to give us your `pubspec.yaml` file as it is.
If you are not formatting the content as it should be, you will no get what you expect. ‎ ‎ ‎

Answer (score 0):

inside your GetMaterialApp at the main file inside theme you should add

```
fontFamily: 'The name of your font in the assets'
```